# Combining standard deviations - given mean, sample size, and SD of two sets?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I have two groups A and B. I know A and B's sample sizes, mean performances on a test (not their individual scores however), and the standard deviations of A and B. I know how to combine them to find the combined mean, but how do I get the standard deviation of that?

Note that they have DIFFERENT sample sizes.

Comment: Back-calculate the variances and then the sums of squares of each group, add the sums of squares together, recalculate the combined variance using the combined mean, and take the square root.